# why did preview stop working from firefox?

Tags: macos, mac, firefox

I just installed adobe reader, and now when I click on a PDF in the browser, it is not opened in preview. Adobe doesn't work either, and I am stuck without having the PDF viewed at all.

I right clicked on a PDF, and preview is still my default viewer.

So this:

http://www.ehow.com/how_6764524_make-preview-default-pdf-viewer.html

is not helping.

Any ideas? I want to be able to use Preview in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we want firefox to handle a specific file format with a specific application, I would recommend checking firefox configuration from its preferences menu by:

Clicking Firefox from upper left corner and selecting Preferences from the menu.

On the preferences window choose 'Applications' at the top of the window.

There should be a search box. type PDF and on the action side click your preferred program.

This should associate preview as the default pdf viewer whenever a pdf file is clicked.

Comment: I'm not sure which version of Firefox you have, but in the case of my Firefox (FF 16.0.1), this didn't work as written, but the process was similar - rather than 'Preferences', it was 'Options->Options', and while a search for PDF failed, 'Adobe Acrobat Document' showed up and I could change it there.

Comment: I followed these instructions, and now preview shows as the default viewer for PDF files, but it is still trying to open adobe. any ideas?

Comment: this solved my problem: http://www.howtogeek.com/123617/how-to-enable-firefoxs-built-in-pdf-reader/